# Add a computed field in a select using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to add a computed field in my select result using Eloquent.

```
$dbEntry->query->select('id', '(s1 + s2) as scoreSum')->toSql();
// "select `id`, `(s1` as `s2)` from `mytable`"
```

I would expect:

```
// "select `id`, `s1` + `s2` as scoreSum from `mytable`"
```

Context: in my real world stuff, what I am computing is an haversine formula (on a limited set of entries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a raw query instead, e.g. like this:

```
->select(DB::raw('id, (s1 + s2) as scoreSum'))
```

Make sure you import the `DB` as well.

Comment: Are we sure that the raw query is required?

Comment: Essentially anything that requires an operation needs to use a raw query. Since you have one (the addition), a raw query should be needed. I'm about 95 % sure. :)

Comment: @AsTeR You could limit the raw query to just the computed field: `->select('id', DB::raw('(s1 + s2) as scoreSum'))`, but you still need the raw query to do what you want to do.