# Laravel - selecting and filtering by computed columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to have some query like following:

```sql
SELECT *, (qty * price) AS total_price FROM orders;
```

I've tried this:

```php
Order::query()
    ->withoutGlobalScopes()
    ->select(['*', '(qty * price) AS total_price'])
    ->get();
```

But throws an error:

> 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(qty * price)' in 'field list'...

What is the right way to do this?

Is it `DB::raw(...)` ?

---

#### Update:

I've tried these too:

```php
Order::query()
    ->withoutGlobalScopes()
    ->select(['*', DB::raw('(qty * price) AS total_price')])
    ->where('total_price', '<=', $user->balance)
    ->get();
```

```php
Order::query()
    ->withoutGlobalScopes()
    ->select(DB::raw('*, (qty * price) AS total_price'))
    ->where('total_price', '<=', $user->balance)
    ->get();
```

It says:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_price' in 'where clause'

---

#### Update 2

In case of use `select(DB::raw('*, (qty * price) AS total_price'))`, if I don't use `->where('total_price...` it works fine, but the second I add `->where` it throws the error that says *Unknown column*

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36406740/1317091) answer might answer your question.

Comment: I think you should consider every questions as a new challenge not a duplicate of old questions, I've searched and found that answer already, but didn't solved my problem. so... @Braggae

Comment: `->select('*', DB::raw('(qty * price) AS total_price'))`

Comment: @IGP tried that too, Still says unknown column I don't know why !

Comment: Oh right, I missed the where clause. You can't use computed columns in the where clause.  Use `whereRaw` for that. `->whereRaw('(qty * price) <= ?', [$user->balance])`